# How to handle error function in python / django

Tags: python, django, function, error-handling

I am new in python and django, right now I am trying to develop face recognition api and I get error, here is the error log: https://gist.github.com/wahyu-handayani/9d8338741ee50697332f7ed63f9769e2
when that error happens, the server will off so I just want to throw or return something in postman, so that the server will still on. So far I have been doing `try` and `except`

```
try:
        # some codes
        cv2.imshow('Frame', image) # here is the code that makes the error happens
        
except Exception as e:
        return JsonResponse({"Error": str(e)})
```

but still.. it does't go to `Exception` block. How to do the right way for `try` and `except` in a function ?

Answer (score 0):

a quick fix can be ,

create a default error page in the templates and display that when there is any exception

```
def anyfunction(request):
    try:
        #some code
    except:
        context = {
            'error' : "Error  message of that page !"
        }
        return render(request, 'error/errorpage.html',context)
```

errorpage.html is a template that shows the error :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}

{% block title %}

Error !

{% endblock %}

{% block body %}

<h1>oops Page error!!!</h1>
<br>
<div class="jumbotron">
    {{error}}
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

Thus your server doesnt go down and you can continue working on the webpage

Comment: Thank you @SANGEETHSUBRAMONIAM, I have tried your code but I still get the server is off when I add this code ```cv2.imshow('Frame', image)```, but when I delete tahat code and change into ```raise Exception("err")```, I get the respond from postman like your answer and the server is still on.. is there a way to catch uncaught error from ```cv2.imshow('Frame', image)```

Comment: I think the error occurs before hitting the try-except block.

Comment: @Martins I have tried that the error happen after adding ```cv2.imshow('Frame', image)``` because when I delete this line code, the program still runs well